# Exchanging Settings from Options Page to Content-Script in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I got a chrome extension which has the following manifest (part)

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://plus.google.com/*"],      
      "js": ["jquery-1.10.2.min.js","filter.js"]
    }
  ],
  "options_page": "settings.html",
```

I successfully read and write settings into the localstorage from within the "settings.js" which is called from the settings-page "settings.html"

Now I need to access these values from the content-script "filter.js"

I followed the example of http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html creating a listener to the "settings.js" and a request to the "filter.js":

settings.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell);
    });
```

filter.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```

It does not look like the listener and the request can "find each other".

All I get on the console is:

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined
        at chrome-extension://opojapnnibghjncfphindgjhddljcgej/settings.js:30:23
        at extensions::messaging:320:11
        at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
        at Event.dispatchToListener (extensions::event_bindings:386:22)
        at Event.dispatch_ (extensions::event_bindings:371:27)
        at Event.dispatch (extensions::event_bindings:392:17)
        at dispatchOnDisconnect (extensions::messaging:280:27)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It may be simpler for you if you use the `chrome.storage` API instead of `localstorage` to save your settings. You can access `chrome.storage` directly from the content script, so you wont need to send messages to the background.

Comment: Should have known that earlier.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by myself by adding an event page to the manifest:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["loader.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
```

where I put the listeners and called those from the options script as well as from the content script.